# How to use WCF service running on Windows Service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, windows-services

I am new at WCF. I have created a new WCF service which has one method called SendFax(). It is running on windows service. I want other users to use this method but how? I installed the windows service with installutil.exe and it is running now. I guess my WCF service is listening. How can I reach this service? My windows service code is here:

```
public partial class WCFWinService : ServiceBase
{
    ServiceHost serviceHost;

    public WCFWinService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceName = "Digiturk FaxPro WCF";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(FaxPro.WCFWindowsService.WCFWinService));
        serviceHost.Open();                
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

WCF Interface code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SendFax(....);
}
```

WCF Service Code:

```
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{             

    public void SendFax(...)
    { ... }
```

Any suggestions?

---

App.Config is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Digiturk.FaxPro.WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService"
                contract="localhost.IWCFService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to this service at the defined address:

```
 http://example.com:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Digiturk.FaxPro.WcfServiceLibrary/‌Service1/
```

It's a SOAP service - so you'll need a SOAP-capable testing tool, like SoapUI or the WCF Test Client (just a browser will not work). You can get the WSDL for the service at the above address by appending `?wsdl` to the URL.

Comment: You can connect to this service at the defined address - `http://ServerName:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Digiturk.FaxPro.WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/`. It's a **SOAP** service - so you'll need a SOAP-capable testing tool, like SoapUI or the WCF Test Client (just a browser will not work). You can get the WSDL for the service at the above address by appending `?wsdl` to the URL